# Can I login using Google Play Games Plugin on iOS without opening Safari?

Tags: plugins, safari, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, review

So my iOS app recently got rejected for:

The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for logging in, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able log in without opening Safari first. In addition Logging in should be optional and the user should be able to chose to do this within the app if they would like. It should not be forced onto them when the app is launched.

I've fixed the automatic login to wait for the player to press the login button first, however I don't know how to fix the part about having to open Safari to log the player into google to enable access to the leaderboards/achievements.

I use the official google play games plugin.

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but I just got my own rejection for this. I did NOT have automatic logging in, but still got dinged on the "opens a web page in mobile Safari for logging in".